# Need to customize directory structure of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory

I Need to customise directory structure of WordPress for the security purpose. I also need to hide the `wp-config.php`

And need to change the URL of wordpress admin for editor too.

Answer (score 2):

1. Hide config? you can deny access to it in your .htaccess

> ```
> <Files wp-config.php>
>    Order Allow,Deny
>    Deny from all
> </Files>
> ```

2. with regards to changing the structure you should read [this post](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/change-wordpress-file-directory-structure/)
3. You can rename your admin slug with any [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the plugin [Wp hide and security enhancer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-security-enhancer/), It will do the job.Using this no one will know you actually run a WordPress.As well as you can hide your wp-admin url.